# Zend Optimizer на php 5.3.X

Tags: php

Нужно установить эту штуку на сервер, иначе не будут работать некоторые файлы.

Кто сталкивался кто может помочь?

Везде написано что только ZendGuardLoader для 5ки php поможет, но не помогает

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.Для PHP 5.3 возможно использование только Zend Guard. Поддержка Zend Optimizer в PHP 5.3 отсутствует. Для решения проблемы возможно два варианта:

1. Использовать PHP 5.2 совместно с Zend Optimzer (если сейчас на сервере 5.3 необходимо провести downgrade);
2. Обратиться к разработчику скрипта для того, чтобы он предоставил версию для Zend Guard, т.к. скрипты, закодированные для работы с Zend Optimizer под Guard'ом не работают.

Второй вариант является предпочтительным с точки зрения дальнейшей поддержки проекта. При этом первый вариант является, как правило, наиболее простым в реализации.